# MS Access - Continuous form custom text entry

Tags: sql, ms-access, continuous-forms

Good Morning All,

I am wrestling with a problem with continuous forms.

I have a continuous form based on a query that pulls transaction information from a table.

I want to have text box on each row where the user can override the fee value, at which point when the submit button is clicked the overridden information is written into a second table in the database.

When I add an unbound text box onto the continuous form I end up with all entries reflecting the amount I have just entered.
If I add a dummy column onto the SQL query, I am unable to edit the information.

Is there a way to do this? Below is an example of the form input I am shooting for:

***Snip:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in Access.

I think the closest you can get, is to display the value from the secondary table in your continuous form; and then, after some user input (focus into the textbox, or double-click the text box, or button click), prompt the user to enter a value using either the VBA `InputBox` function, or leveraging the built-in Zoom box. Check that the user-entered value is a valid number, update your external table, and refresh the query results.

You might also create a custom form to validate the input.